# How to access multi-valued dictionaries in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following dictionary:

```
{1:['a&b','b-c','c-d'],2:['e orf ','f-k-p','g']}
```

I want to print the key and values from this dictionary
I tried the following code:

```
for (var key in dictionary) {
    // check if the property/key is defined in the object itself, not in parent
    if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {           
        console.log(key, dictionary[key]);
    }
}
```

I am just getting some random numbers.How could I solve it?
My output:

```
key:34639values:mkey:34640values:akey:34641values:tkey:34642values:hkey:34643values:ekey:34644values:mkey:34645values:akey:34646values:tkey:34647values:ikey:34648values:ckey:34649values:skey:34650values: key:34651values:pkey:34652values:rkey:34653values:okey:34654values:bkey:34655values:lkey:34656values:ekey:34657values:mkey:34658values:
```

I want the output as:

```
keys: 1,2
values: ['a&b','b-c','c-d'],['e orf ','f-k-p','g']
```

```js
var dictionary = {1:['a','b','c'],2:['e','f','g']}
for (var key in dictionary) {
    // check if the property/key is defined in the object itself, not in parent
    if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
        console.log(`key: `, key);
        console.log(`values: `, dictionary[key]);
    }
}
```

Edit:
Actually the dictionary is taken as string. How can I typecast it to dictionary?

Comment: please add expected output

Comment: Your code is working fine and it returning exact same output

Answer (score -1):

You can get object keys with

```
Object.keys(dictionary)
```

which will result with:  array of two elements: `["1", "2"]`.

When you have key of object, you can get it's content using simple for loop:

```
for(let key of Object.keys(dictionary))
    console.log(dictionary[key])
```

result:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
["e", "f", "g"]
```

Don't forget about `console.table(dictionary)`. For simple table structures it may help with displaying.

Answer (score -2):

```
var dictionary = {1:['a','b','c'],2:['e','f','g']}
var keys = [];
var values = [];
for (var key in dictionary) {
    // check if the property/key is defined in the object itself, not in parent
    if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key);
        values.push(dictionary[key]);
    }
}

console.log(`keys: `, keys);
console.log(`values: `, values);
```

Comment: I have my special characters in the values column and when I try your code,I get the following output:```key:34639values:mkey:34640values:akey:34641values:tkey:34642values:hkey:34643values:ekey:34644values:mkey:34645values:akey:34646values:tkey:34647values:ikey:34648values:ckey:34649values:skey:34650values: key:34651values:pkey:34652values:rkey:34653values:okey:34654values:bkey:34655values:lkey:34656values:ekey:34657values:mkey:34658values:     ```

Comment: @SriTest can you create a demo to show that you are getting this output?

Answer (score -2):

I have created this below utility for fulfilling your requirement.

```js
let data = {1:['a&b','b-c','c-d'],2:['e orf ','f-k-p','g']}

const keys = Object.keys(data)
const values = Object.values(data)
console.log(`Keys: ${keys.join()}`)

let result = values.reduce((result, value) => { result.push(JSON.stringify(value)); return result}, []).join()
console.log(`Values: ${result}`)
```

Hope this helps.